# Algorithm: Minimal path alternating colors

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let G be a directed weighted graph with nodes colored black or white, and all weights non-negative.  No other information is specified--no start or terminal vertex.

I need to find a path (not necessarily simple) of minimal weight which alternates colors at least `n` times.  My first thought is to run Kosaraju's algorithm to get the component graph, then find a minimal path between the components.  Then you could select nodes with in-degree equal to zero since those will have at least as many color alternations as paths which start at components with in-degree positive.  However, that also means that you may have an unnecessarily long path.

I've thought about maybe trying to modify the graph somehow, by perhaps making copies of the graph that black-to-white edges or white-to-black edges point into, or copying or deleting edges, but nothing that I'm brain-storming seems to work.

Comment: Could we revisit node? what about other constraints? number of node? how large is `n`?

Comment: I would just run Dijkstra and add the number of alternations seen so far to the node state. This will essentially duplicate the nodes.

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes, you can revisit nodes.  Number of nodes is a variable, you can call it |V|.  n is an arbitrary constant.  We want an efficient (log linear) algorithm.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Plain Dijkstra would require specifying a start, though.  Here, paths that alternate sufficiently many times may start anywhere.  If you run Dijkstra's at every vertex you get an inefficient algorithm.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that you have a start. You might want to add that to the question. I admit that it is kind of there already.

Comment: I believe that if we assign some reward or using an edge that connects two nodes of different colors such that the shortest path taking the reward into account has exactly `n` such edges, that path will be the optimal answer. We can then use a binary search to find the value of the reward that we need if we can find an algorithm to compute the shortest path between any two vertices with negative edge weights. I don't have a proof of this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments mention using Dijkstra's algorithm, and in fact there is a way to make this work. If we create an new "root" vertex in the graph, and connect every other vertex to it with a directed edge, we can run a modified Dijkstra's algorithm from the root outwards, terminating when a given path's inversions exceeds `n`. It is important to note that we must allow revisiting each vertex in the implementation, so the key of each vertex in our priority queue will not be merely `node_id`, but a tuple `(node_id, inversion_count)`, representing that vertex on its `i`th visit. In doing so, we implicitly make `n` copies of each vertex, one per potential visit. Visually, we are effectively making `n` copies of our graph, and translating the edges between each `(black_vertex, white_vertex)` pair to connect between the `i` and `i+1`th inversion graphs. We run the algorithm until we reach a path with `n` inversions. Alternatively, we can connect each vertex on the `n`th inversion graph to a "sink" vertex, and run any conventional path finding algorithm on this graph, unmodified. This will run in `O(n(E + Vlog(nV)))` time. You could optimize this quite heavily, and also consider using A* instead, with the `smallest_inversion_weight * (n - inversion_count)` as a heuristic.

Furthermore, another idea hit me regarding using knowledge of the inversion requirement to speedup the search, but I was unable to find a way to implement it without exceeding `O(V^2)` time. The idea is that you can use an addition-chain (like binary exponentiation) to decompose the shortest `n`-inversion path into two smaller paths, and rinse and repeat in a divide and conquer fashion. The issue is you would need to construct tables for the shortest `i`-inversion path from any two vertices, which would be `O(V^2)` entries per `i`, and `O(V^2logn)` overall. To construct each table, for every entry in the preceding table you'd need to append `V` other paths, so it'd be `O(V^3logn)` time overall. Maybe someone else will see a way to merge these two ideas into a `O((logn)(E + Vlog(Vlogn)))` time algorithm or something.

Comment: There is a problem with Dijkstra's algo, as node can be revisited, so you need to added on more dimension into the state. (node, step), so, not sure the time complexity will be sufficient.

Comment: @PhamTrung a node should only be visited once per inversion count. If once your visit node `node_C` with 3 color inversions, no shorter path exists to visit `node_C` with exactly 3 color inversions. So we only need `(node, inversions)`, not `(node, step)`

Comment: Hmm, so let's say there is a cycle between A - B, and the minimum path is just keep looping between those two, how could you handle that case?

Comment: @PhamTrung And because each `(node, inversions)` pair can only progress to any one `inversion` variant of a given `other_node` (3 inversions `node_C` can only go to 3 inversions `node_D` (if its the same color) or 4 inversions `node_D`, not 5, or 2, etc), it only scales the number of nodes, not the dimensionality.

Comment: @PhamTrung The path in your example would then be `(node_A, 0)`, `(node_B, 1)`, `(node_A, 2)`, `(node_B, 3)`. Very similar to if it counted steps, but different in that it counts inversions, and thus is limited by `n`.

Comment: Hmm, I think you and I mean almost the same thing, ha ha, thanks for explanation.

Comment: Could you please explain what an inversion is (or point to an explanation)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן an inversion is a transition from a black node to a white node (or vice versa). In our path, the number of inversions is the number of edges in our path that connect two differently colored nodes.